# Modify a value in a foreach to change another one

Tags: javascript, php, foreach, textbox

I've got a question about this `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $html.='<tr>
              <td>'.$row['product_name'].'</td>
              <td>'.recupHourMinSec($row['date_add']).'</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="preparationTime" id="preparationTime" value="15" /></td>
              <td>'.date('H:i:s',  strtotime("+$preparationTime mins".$row['date_add'])).'</td>
              <td>'.$row['lastname'].' '.$row['firstname'].'</td>
              <td>'.$row['phone'].'</td>
              <td>'.$row['phone_mobile'].'</td>'.'</tr>';
}
```

I would like to change the value of the `textBox` on the website to get the time when the order will be ready.

I want to add the value of the text field `preperationTime` to the time the order was taken, 20:00:00 for example, and display it on the page, 20:15:00 in this example.

How to get the value of the `preparationTime` text box every time we change it to modify the time when the order will be ready ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `date` and `strtotime` for this:-

```
<td>'.date('H:i:s',  strtotime('+15 mins'.$row['date_add'])).'</td>
```

As you comment earlier, try like this:-

```
   $value = 10;
  '<td>'.date('H:i:s',  strtotime("+$value mins".$row['date_add'])).'</td>';
```

**you can change  `$value` dynamically.thanks.**

Comment: but i want to change the value of preparationTime when ever i want and i would like that the result changes in the meantime

Comment: as i said define variable outside of foreach loop and put in value filed of input type of text. after that every thing happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try as this

As you said you were getting value within `$row['date_add']` variable `20:00:00`
Here using [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) will convert your time into timestamp and you can add values within [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) as `strtotime('+15 mins')` with the current time and using `date` function you can format it as your desire

```
<td>'.date('H:i:s',  strtotime('+15 mins'.$row['date_add'])).'</td>
```

You can add your dynamic values as

```
date('H:i:s',  strtotime("$your_values mins".$row['date_add']))
```

Comment: I don't want to always add 15 minutes, it's just a default value.

Comment: Then when you need to add 15minutes. Update your question with expected output

Comment: I changed my question !

Comment: What you really wanted to show the data or need to save the data